# How is quean related to queen?

Tags: etymology

To my untrained eye, the words *quean* and *queen* look suspiciously similar, although they are quite different in meaning; so how did it come to be like that? Is this a coincidence, or are they etymologically related? And, if so, how are they related?

Answer (score 4):

*Quean* and *queen* are in fact related. Both are related to Proto-Germanic **kwenon* or similar, "wife, woman"; Proto-Germanic is the ur-language that later gave rise to English, German, Dutch, Scandinavian.

The Proto-Germanic root is in turn descended from Proto-Indo-European root **gwen*- "woman"; Proto-Indo-European is the speculated/reconstructed ur-language of all speakers of the modern Indo-European languages, such as English, German, French, Latin, Greek, Persian, Hindi, etc.

Note that Ancient Greek *gunê*, stem *gunaik-*, "woman", which gave rise to English *gynaecology, misogyny*, is from the same Proto-Indo-European root.

> *[Quean](https://www.etymonline.com/word/queen)* "young, robust woman," Old English *cwene* "woman," also "female serf, hussy, prostitute" (as in *portcwene* "public woman"), from Proto-Germanic **kwenon* (source also of Old Saxon *quan*, Old High German *quena*, Old Norse *kona*, Gothic *qino* "wife, woman"), from **PIE root **gwen***- "woman." Popular 16c.-17c. in sense "hussy." Sense of "effeminate homosexual" is recorded from 1935, especially in Australian slang.

Comment: _Quean_ vs _queen_ is one of the stock classroom example of what can happen when sound changes create lexical ambiguities: one possibility is that one of the two competing words drops out of the language, and this is an example of that. Another possibility is that one of the two competing words will be modified so it's not competing anymore; an example of that is German _liegen_, which -- like English _lie_ still is -- used to be ambiguous between 'tell a lie' and 'recline_. But German borrowed a dialect word _lügen_ for the 'tell a lie' sense and kept _liegen_ for 'recline'.

Comment: The OED entries for the words say that "queen" and "quean" are from different ablaut grades of the same PIE root, which I understand as implying that they had distinct forms already in Proto-Germanic ("queen" with a long vowel, "quean" with a short vowel).

Comment: @sumelic: I puzzled with that too. Etymonline says on *queen*: *"from Proto-Germanic \*kwoeniz (source also of Old Saxon quan ...)*". And in *quean*: *"from Proto-Germanic \*kwenon (source also of Old Saxon quan ...)"*. From this it should follow that, if *quan* is from both *\*kwoeniz* and *\*kwenon*, then those two lines must come together and *queen* and *quean* must have a common ancestor in Proto-Germanic. I figured perhaps those two spellings of the Proto-Germanic word might be different hypotheses about the spelling of the word. Or they might be different stages in the same line. ...

Comment: ... So I followed Etymonline. But I see now that the OED says it in a different way. Perhaps Etymonline is imprecise and therefore wrong? Or is it possible that the common ancestor of *\*kwoeniz* (ablauted form) and *\*kwenon* (lengthened form) should have still existed in Proto-Germanic, whatever it was? And/or was *\*kwoeniz* an ablauted form of *\*kwenon*? That's how I read it when I wrote my answer, but I don't know enough about Proto-Germanic and its phonology...

Comment: I think Etymonline might be mistaken or using outdated sources. I'm not familiar with "oe" as a sound in the inventory of Proto-Germanic; Wiktionary gives the reconstructed form of the ancestor of *queen* as [kwēniz](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/kw%C4%93niz). The word [kwenǭ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/kwen%C7%AD), ancestor of *quean,* is supposed to have been the form with the short vowel.

Comment: (I think -ǭ vs. -on is just a notational variant--Wiktionary's guide to [Proto-Germanic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:About_Proto-Germanic#Vowels) says "Nasal vowels are represented by an ogonek (ą, į, ų, ǭ etc.). Other sources may use the tilde (ã, ĩ, ũ) or the letter n following the vowel (an, in, un)")

Comment: Old Saxon *quān* looks like it would be from *kwēniz* rather than from *kwenǭ,* based on the length of the vowel, and the fact that as far as I can tell  short e did not have a or ā as a reflex in Old Saxon.

Comment: @sumelic: So if I interpret you correctly, *\*kwenon–\*kwenǭ* was certainly not the common ancestor of *queen* and *quean*? Is it possible that they still do have a common ancestor in Proto-Germanic?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I don't think we would expect "ee" (which is usually from Middle English close long /eː/) as a possible reflex of Proto-Germanic short *e.

Comment: @sumelic: Okay, well, I have no idea, but I have changed it to "both are related to".

Answer (score 3):

According to the OED entries for these words, *queen* and *quean* are from different ablaut grades of the same Proto-Indo-European root. Proto-Indo-European or "PIE" is the reconstructed ancestor of the Indo-European languages, which include things like English, Latin and its descendants (the Romance languages), and Sanskrit and its descendants/related languages.

The term "ablaut" refers to a phenomenon where many roots in Proto-Indo-European seem to have had multiple forms ("ablaut grades") with different vowels. In the case of *queen* and *quean,* it seems that both can be traced to a root *gʷ-n-, but the first comes from a form with a long vowel (*ē), while the second comes from a form with a short vowel (*e). I don't know the details about what exactly the PIE forms are thought to have been. As far as I can tell, scholars have not yet established a consensus about the exact reason for the difference in vowel length between the two Proto-Germanic words: if you're interested in technical discussion about this point and a list of some relevant literature, check out page 102 of "[Archaisms and innovations](https://static-curis.ku.dk/portal/files/117198621/Ph.d._2014_Simmelkj_r.pdf)", a PhD thesis by Bjarne Simmelkjær Sandgaard Hansen (2014).

The originally short vowel of *quean* would have been lengthened in Middle English, resulting in a long but open-mid vowel [ɛː] (as opposed to the long close-mid vowel [eː] that would have been used in the Middle English pronunciation of the word *queen*). But after the Great Vowel Shift, [ɛː] and [eː] merged in most contexts as Modern English [iː]. This merger was less extensive in certain regional dialects, however. Interestingly, the OED entry for *quean* says

> Outside literary use, M. L. Samuels ( *Linguistic Evolution* (1972) 68) observes that continuing currency in sense 1 is mostly confined to those regional varieties in which this merger (and hence homophony with *queen* n.) did not occur.

In Proto-Germanic (the common ancestor of the Germanic languages), Wiktionary gives the reconstructed forms as **[kwēniz](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/kw%C4%93niz)* (for the ancestor of *queen*) and **[kwenǭ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/kwen%C7%AD)* (for the ancestor of *quean*).

Comment: +1 So are you positive that the ablaut occurred according to the rules of Proto-Indo-European phonology and not Proto-Germanic phonology—and, as a consequence, that it occurred in Proto-Indo-European and not in Proto-Germanic?

Comment: @Cerberus: I don't know to what extent ablaut continued to be a productive process in Proto-Germanic. However, I haven't found any source that shows Proto-Germanic as having a single word with a declension containing a long and short ablaut grade of PIE *gʷ-n-. My impression is that ablaut alternations in noun declensions were lost fairly early on, although Wikipedia's article on [Proto-Germanic Grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Germanic_grammar) does indicate that some such alternations existed.